# Is the arduino nano 33 IOT schematic wrong?

Tags: arduino-nano

As am i was copying the schematics of the arduino nano 33 IOT from the [Official arduino schematic](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/NANO33IoTV2.0_sch.pdf) i noticed something was wrong in the schematic, specifically in the PRTV5V component

Here is a snip on the schematic
[image]

It would seems that the pin numbering on the PRTR5V is wrong. Here are snippits from the [PRTR5V Datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PRTR5V0U2F_PRTR5V0U2K.pdf)

[image]
[image]

The sample schematic does look like the same of the arduino but if you look at it using the pin number it is different.For example on the arduino schematic pin 2 is at the middle of the two diodes, while on the datasheed pin 2 is before the diodes.

Now which one should i follow? Did arduino intentionally pin it that way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct. You are looking at the wrong datasheet.

This is the correct one:

- https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PRTR5V0U2X.pdf

Comment: Thank you good sir ! you just saved me from buying the wrong part :)